# customization of input range slider and its pointer

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I am using the range slider in my website for showing the image zooming and zoomout by using "range" option but i want to change this as a vertical slider and want to display customized thumb button also

```
<input class="zoom-range vertical" type="range" orient="vertical" step="0.05" min="0.1" max="1">
```

And css for the different browsers like

```
input[type=range].vertical
{
    writing-mode: bt-lr; /* IE */
    -webkit-appearance: slider-vertical; /* WebKit */
    width: 0px;
    height: 100px;
    margin-top: 20px;
}
```

The above css will do the slider as vertical but how can i change the pointer color and hide the width of scroller?

I am getting my slider like this

[image: currently i have]

And i want to make my slider as shown in below

[image: Want to Make like this]

Please help me to sort out this issue

It's working for Firefox but for chrome browser if i will use the properties

```
input[type=range]::-webkit-slider-thumb {
    background: blue;
    -webkit-appearance: slider-vertical;
}
```

these two are not applying to the pointer in chrome. And if i will do `-webkit-appearance: none;` then the pointer color is changing

Comment: have you used jQuery UI range slider?

Answer (score 1):

Try this css:

```
input[type=range] {
    -webkit-appearance: none; // important
    margin: 18px 0;
    width: 100%;
    transform:rotate(90deg); //for vertical slider
    outline:none;
}
input[type=range]::-webkit-slider-runnable-track {
    width: 1px;
    height: 8.4px;
    cursor: pointer;
    animate: 0.2s;
    background: #BFBFBF; // you can change it accordingly
    border-radius: 1.3px;
}
input[type=range]::-webkit-slider-thumb {
    height: 36px;
    width: 16px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    background: #004C8F; //Your preferred color
    cursor: pointer;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    margin-top: -14px;
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/esvqpkbf/

Fiddle also has CSS for mozilla, you can modify it accordingly.

Comment: Hello KK, Thanks for your answer. I have tried this but it's working for firefox only. I am not able to change the thumb(pointer) for chrome and IE browser and is it possible to hide the border of slider?

Comment: You can set background-color of slider/ track to transparent to hide it. It should work for you.

Comment: Yeah i got this and again the issue is coming in chrome, pls look at my question it's edited.

Comment: You have to change -webkit-appearance: none; and then rotate the slider using css transform. I think it's there in the jsfiddle

Comment: Thanks KK, I have tried by giving -webkit-appearance: none; and rotation also please check in chrome browser and the slider-thumb is going horizantal http://jsfiddle.net/email501/yddtz5zu/ and correct me if i am doing wrong

Comment: You need to customize the height and width. Try this : http://jsfiddle.net/yddtz5zu/2/